# PowerPoint: How can I select objects only partially covered by selection box (span)?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, selection

Is there a setting for this?

I am used to this mode and am constantly missing objects when trying to select a group.

This is how selection by complete box coverage looks like:

[image]

This is how selection by partial box overage looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's no Options setting for this, but try instead the following:

On the Home tab, at far right, click the triangle next to Select,
then choose "Selection Pane".

In the Selection Pane you can click to select any object or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click to select multiple objects one after the other.